# css left right column fixed

Tags: css

im working on a 3 column webpage. i would like to freeze the left n right column. i tried setting to position:fixed on the left column first but everything other div just crash to the left.

any idea??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`position:fixed` takes the element out of the normal "flow" of elements.  I typically circumvent this by setting `margin-left` of the middle column to be equal to the width of the left column plus the desired gutter.  For example, if the left column is 250px and the gutter is 25px then the `margin-left` of the middle column would be 275px.

Sample code (this keeps the middle column fluid in width):

```
#wrapper { position: relative; min-width: 800px; max-width: 1000px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
#left-col { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 250px; }
#right-col { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 250px; }
#middle-col { position: relative; margin-left: 275px; min-width: 250px; max-width: 450px; }

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-col"> left </div>
    <div id="middle-col"> middle </div>
    <div id="right-col"> right </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @nuttynibbles, it isn't see my example

Comment: It's not necessary.  I added it to provide three things:  1.) Centering of the content area, 2.) max-width of the content area, 3.) and position: relative.  You could just use `<body>` if you wanted, but often I find I have a header and footer outside of the column area so having it in a wrapper makes it easier to work with.

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you. It can even be adapted such that the central column width can be completely dictated by the two fixed outer columns, by setting `middle-col`'s `margin-right` as well as a `margin-left`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set margin on the center div to keep the space for the other two.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pfxxL/

```
#left {
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
}

#right {
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
}

#center {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    height: 750px;
    background: green;
}

<div id="left">
    left left<br/>
    left left<br/>
    left left<br/>
</div>
<div id="center">
    center
</div>
<div id="right">
    right right<br/>
    right right<br/>
    right right<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I was the first to answer your question, to be honest. But if you found that T. Stone's answer suits your situation better than his answer is better.